# Why does including Angular Material's CSS break the CSS rule for full-screen rendering of a background image?

Tags: html, css, background, viewport, angular-material

In this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CJE2JBewxHHz8F8e0x66?p=preview), I have a background image that covers the entire viewport through the CSS rule: `background-size:cover;`.

However, simply including the Angular Material CSS file changes this behavior as you can see in the linked plunker such that the image does not stay anchored to the viewport but scrolls along with the page content.

What is causing this change and how can we get the old behavior back while using Angular Material?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if I disable the body background color it fixes it. Here is the screenshot.
http://screencast.com/t/NvS3xmaL
So you can play with overflow property. Overflow: auto will work.

Comment: Can you please share a working plnkr? Removing the color didn't fix it for me, neither did setting the overflow property.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't used Plnkr before. Could you try this:
html,body {overflow:auto;}
http://screencast.com/t/mwKbuOCB3ZJ7

Comment: Yes, here is a nice read for you: http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `body` CSS that Angular Material sets in your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CJE2JBewxHHz8F8e0x66?p=preview) we see the following:

[image]

Disabling the `background` style fixes the problem.

[image]

However, with the latest Angular Material CSS (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css) this style is not set so the problem will no longer appear - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KSlFA81LGO4Lma07AdXj?p=preview)